# Making a container inside the body scrollable using the spacebar by default

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following markup in my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in my CSS code, I have the following:

```
html,
body {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.page {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

While this may seem a bit odd, it solves a few crucial things for my application. Anyway, the idea is that the `.content` container is the one that holds the overflowing content. Anyway, when the page is first loaded, a lot of users prefer to use the spacebar to scroll. Since the body isn't scrollable, nothing happens.

How can I change the target of the spacebar to scroll the `.content` container instead of the body by default? I tried the following:

```
document.activeElement = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0]
```

However, this did not work. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your solution:

for css :

```
html,body 
{
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   overflow: hidden; // i changed this line
}
.page {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll; // i changed this line
}
```

for JavaScript:

```
 // you can use getElementById if your element is unique in the page.
 let container = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
     container.scrollTop = 40; // to set how much pixels you have to scroll
     window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault(); // to prevent the default spacebar event.
            if(e.code === 'Space'){
               container.scrollBy(0,container.scrollTop);
             }
      });
```